# PHP Reload page when clicking link

Tags: javascript, php, caching, hyperlink, reload

I want to reload my page when the user clicks a link.
I was working with the `window.location.reload(true)` function and this reloaded the page but it used the cached version. I want it to reload it completely! 
I am using Google Chrome to test my homepage!

Current Code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<img src="';
    echo $image;
    echo '" width="120" height="100"></td>';
    $link = '<a href="deletesingle.php?bild=' . $image . '" target="_blank"' .  'onClick="window.location.reload(true);">';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $link;
    echo 'L&ouml;schen!</a>';
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Does! Your! Problem! Involve! So! Much! Drama! That! It! Requires! Exclamation! Points!!!!??? try adding a cache-buster value to the page's url, which changes every time you click, which will cause the browser to fetch a fresh version instead of just redrawing the cached copy.

Comment: Or disable all cache control directives.

Comment: I guess you want to show the new list after image/item deletion? If so, why not redirect after deleting your image in the .php file?

Comment: user3165879's idea is good. Thanks.
And Marc B. whats your problem? I used 2 exclamation marks?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is named :

**list.php**

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
$image = $files[$i];
echo '<tr><td>';
echo '<img src="';
echo $image;
echo '" width="120" height="100"></td>';
$link = '<a href="deletesingle.php?bild=' . $image . '">';
echo '<td>';
echo $link;
echo 'L&ouml;schen!</a>';
echo '</td></tr>';
```

In **deletesingle.php**

```
//Your code to delete image

//redirect back to list.php
header('location: deletesingle.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the _blank value ion the attribut target send the request to a new page or a new tab.
You could call your deletesingle.php page and redirect to your list with a parameter, like ?no_cache=1

Then, in your listing page, if the $_GET['no_cache'] is set, force the header to prevent caching

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["no_cache"] && $_GET["no_cache"] == 1) {
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me capture your requirement with a simplified model:

You have a current page, let's call it "images.php". It lists out the images with a delete button to each.

If you click on any link on the current page without using window.reload, it will load without caching. But you'd also like the page to carry out the delete action. It's best to combine the delete logic with the list.

```
<?php
//images.php

if ($action=='delete'&&is_numeric($_GET['imageid'])){
  //delete the image here
}

//list the images here
...
}
```

Set your new delete link to images.php?action=delete&imageid=*imageid*

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
print "<a href=\"$page\">Reload this page</a>";
?>
```

Comment: How does this bypass the cache?

Comment: dunno. But it does, at least in my test in Firefox Mac. Apart from that, by simply adding

    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
    
into the head of the page, it should for sure always refresh bypassing any cache in any browser...